# Problems with running GPML in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
covfunc = @covRQard; 
likfunc = @likWeibull; 
meanfunc ={@meanSum {@meanConst,@meanLinear }};

hyp2.cov = [1 ;1;1;1;1;1];    
hyp2.lik = 2;
hyp2.mean = [1;1;1;1;1];
hyp2 = minimize(hyp2, @gp, -10, @infLaplace,meanfunc, covfunc, likfunc, x, y);
```

where `size(x) = 700 x 4, size(y) = 700 x 1`.

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: Inference method failed [Error using  /
>    Matrix dimensions must agree.] .. attempting to continue
>
> In gp at 120
>
> In minimize at 97

Can anyone shed any light on the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Your covariance and mean vectors are different sizes.

Comment: The covariance function covRQard takes D+2 hyperparameters (where D is the number of inputs, in the case 4) and the mean function should take D+1, so I don't think that is the problem

Comment: Well then use [`dbstop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) and debug `gp`. It tells you where the error is...